# lme4::glmer.nb function produces "Error in family$family : $ operator not defined for this S4 class" depending on the order I run models

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

```
library(lme4)

dummy <- as.data.frame(cbind(speed = rpois(100, 10), pop = rep(1:4, each = 25), season = rep(1:2, each = 50), id = seq(1, 100, by = 1)))
dummy2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(speed = c(rnbinom(50, 10, 0.6), rnbinom(50, 10, 0.1)), pop = rep(1:4, each = 25), season = rep(1:2, each = 50), id = seq(1, 100, by = 1)))

poisson <- glmer(speed~pop*season + (1|id),
             data=dummy, family="poisson")
neg.bin <- glmer.nb(speed ~ pop*season + (1|id),
                data=dummy2, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

When I run a script creating a Poisson model before a negative binomial model using the lme4 package, I get the following error when running the neg.bin model:

```
Error in family$family : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

However, if I run the models in the opposite order, I don't the error message.

```
library(lme4)
dummy <- as.data.frame(cbind(speed = rpois(100, 10), pop = rep(1:4, each = 25), season = rep(1:2, each = 50), id = seq(1, 100, by = 1)))
dummy2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(speed = c(rnbinom(50, 10, 0.6), rnbinom(50, 10, 0.1)), pop = rep(1:4, each = 25), season = rep(1:2, each = 50), id = seq(1, 100, by = 1)))
neg.bin <- glmer.nb(speed ~ pop*season + (1|id),
                data=dummy2, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
poisson <- glmer(speed~pop*season + (1|id),
             data=dummy, family="poisson")
```

The neg.bin model example does have convergence warnings, but the same pattern is happening with my actual models which are converging fine. How is running the Poisson model first affecting the neg.bin model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have masked R function `poisson`. The following would work fine (except that there is convergence warning for `neg.bin`):

```
library(lme4)
set.seed(0)
dummy <- as.data.frame(cbind(speed = rpois(100, 10), pop = rep(1:4, each = 25), season = rep(1:2, each = 50), id = seq(1, 100, by = 1)))
dummy2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(speed = c(rnbinom(50, 10, 0.6), rnbinom(50, 10, 0.1)), pop = rep(1:4, each = 25), season = rep(1:2, each = 50), id = seq(1, 100, by = 1)))

## use a different name for your model, say `poisson_fit`
poisson_fit <- glmer(speed~pop*season + (1|id),
         data=dummy, family="poisson")

negbin_fit <- glmer.nb(speed ~ pop*season + (1|id),
            data=dummy2, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

---

Here is the issue. Among the very first few lines of `glmer.nb` there is one line:

```
mc$family <- quote(poisson)
```

So, if you mask `poisson`, correct function `poisson` from `stats` package can not be found.

[Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) has just fixed this issue, by replacing this to:

```
mc$family <- quote(stats::poisson)
```

---

My original observation on `family = "poisson"` and `match.fun` stuff is not the real issue here. It only explains why in routines like `glm` and `mgcv::gam`, it is legitimate to pass a string of `family`.

Comment: nice catch.  I think I may be able to fix this in the development version.

Comment: fixed in development version.

Comment: why  are you sorry?  It's a good answer.  I'm very happy if other people answer `lme4` questions, it saves me the trouble. And yes, you're right.   I think your comments about using `family="poisson"` are incorrect/tangential though.  The problem is that `glmer.nb` *internally* uses `poisson`, not `"poisson"` (or used to)